# SwiftUI Bug Menu when present modal fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I think there is a bug in apple framework. The code below present a sheet in fullscreen when we press a Menu.

The first click is OK but the second click after dismiss the modal (if we want show the modal again) doesn't work, the user need to click 2 times on the button...

Someone has already see this problem ? Something wrong in my code ? Any workaround ? Thanks for your advices :)

```
struct TestView: View {

    @State var presentConfModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Menu("Options") {
            Button("Present", action: placeOrder)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentConfModal) {
            SheetView(present: $presentConfModal)
        }
    }

    func placeOrder() {
        presentConfModal.toggle()
    }

}

struct SheetView: View {

    @Binding var present: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Press to dismiss") {
            present = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, seems to work on simulator 15.4. But not in device below 15.3 (need to test on device 15.4)

Answer (score 0):

seems to work for me, on macos 12.3, using xcode 13.3, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. You could try this approach:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var presentConfModal: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu("ContentView Options") {
            Button("Present", action: placeOrder)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentConfModal) {
            SheetView()  // <-- here
        }
    }
    
    func placeOrder() {
        presentConfModal.toggle()
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("SheetView press to dismiss") {
            dismiss() // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```